# print the length of field (string)

Tags: mongodb

how to print field and length of this field

e.g. I have {name:"aaa"} document is collection "names"

then the expected output is

```
{name:"aaa", name_legth:3}
```

Please help.

Comment: believe me, I did google before having this query. 
unfortunately i am using v 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB versions <3.2 don't have a text aggregation operator to compute length of a string value stored in a field. If you are using version 3.2 or older, you will need to implement the length computation outside the DB (such as in the controller layer of an MVC architecture).

Version 3.4, though, includes several new and useful aggregation operators including the `$strLenCP` operator which should serve your purpose. The usage for your case would be as follows:

```
db.names.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                "name": 1,
                "name_length": { $strLenCP: "$name" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

The documentation for the aggregation operator can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/).